# How to calculate inverse function of a "weird" function like $y=x+\cos x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

As the title said, how to calculate the inverse function of $y = f(x) = x + \cos x$ ?

I found a super function $x = g(y)$ like this:
$x = y -\cos(y-\cos(y-\cos(y-cos(...(y-\cos y)...))))$, with infinite nested loop.
And I use matlab to test it, find that the more nests, the lower approximation error.
So I'm conjecturing if $g(y)$ is the true inverse function of $f(x)$.

If yes, why? And can we reduce the form into some "simpler" finite style?

If not, what should it be? And also why?

###############

Note of changes: Sorry for my poor math knowledge, I cannot find a proper symbol describe what "..." exatly means. how about I use programming language?

```
y = a; % a is a constant    
x = y - cos(y);
for i = 1:10000
   x = y - cos(x);
end
disp(x)
```

Comment: No matter what people are telling you: $\ldots$ is *not* a rigorous mathematical definition. And without that, it's unlikely you get a mathematically rigorous answer, and calling something "super" won't change that. So you may try and do better with your definition of $g(y)$.

Comment: @Professor Vector   Sorry, I didn't make it clear. And I added something to hopefully help you get a better understanding.

Comment: There are three things to keep in mind about inverse functions. (1) Not all functions have an inverse.  (2) It is often difficult to know whether a given function has an inverse.  (3) Even if you know that your function has an inverse, it is often extremely difficult (or simply impossible) to find an explicit formula for the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence in your code is defined by $x_0 = a$ and $x_{n+1} = a - \cos(x_n)$, and you want to set $g(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$. Assume for the moment that the limit exists.  Then of course the limit of $x_{n+1}$ is also $g(a)$, so taking the limit of both sides of $x_{n+1} = a - \cos(x_n)$ gives $g(a) = a - \cos(g(a))$, or $g(a) + \cos(g(a)) = a$, or $f(g(a)) = a$.  That is what we would expect for the inverse of $f$, so this is promising.

To complete the proof you must check 2 more things: (1) that the limit exists, and (2) $g(f(a)) = a$ as well.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! I believe I solve the second problem based on your result. Here are the steps: $g(a)=a−cos(g(a)) $, so $g(f(a)) = f(a) - cos(g(f(a)))$, that is $g(f(a))+cos(g(f(a))) = f(a) $, or $f(g(f(a))) = f(a)$, since $f(x)$ is monotonous, so we have $g(f(a)) = a$.